# R: date difference between (m+1)-th column of n-th row and m-th column of (n+1)-th row

Tags: r, date, dataframe, date-difference

I want to append a column indicating the data difference between `m+1`-th col. of `n`-th row and `m`-th col. of `n+1`-th row.

The data format is as `df`,

```
set.seed(2)
user.list = c('A','B','C')
t = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2015/12/31"), 'days')
st = sort(sample(t, 10))
et = st+30
df = data.frame(
         user=sort(sample(user.list, 10, replace=T)),
         start=st,
         due=et
     )
```

The expected output should be

```
   user      start        due     td
1     A 2015-02-16 2015-03-18    -16
2     A 2015-03-02 2015-04-01    -23
3     A 2015-03-09 2015-04-08     70
4     A 2015-06-17 2015-07-17    197*
5     B 2015-07-15 2015-08-14    -17
6     B 2015-07-28 2015-08-27     17
7     B 2015-09-13 2015-10-13    109*
8     C 2015-10-26 2015-11-25     11
9     C 2015-12-06 2016-01-05    -29
10    C 2015-12-07 2016-01-06     24*
```

with `td` indicating the time difference in unit of day.
For example, for user `A`, -16 is derived from difference between 2015-03-02 and 2015-03-18; -23 is the difference between 2015-03-09 and 2015-04-01, etc. The number with `*` is the last row of every user, which is alternatively derived from the difference between a fixed date 2016-01-30 and 2015-07-17 (for user A).

How can it be solved by an efficient way without `dlply` (divide into list of users), `for` and `if` (scanning each row and see if it is the last one of the user)?

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(user) %>% 
  mutate(start = c(start, as.Date("2016-01-30"))[-1]) %>%
  mutate(td = start - due)
# Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
# Groups: user [3]
# 
#      user      start        due       td
#    (fctr)     (date)     (date)   (dfft)
# 1       A 2015-03-02 2015-03-18 -16 days
# 2       A 2015-03-09 2015-04-01 -23 days
# 3       A 2015-06-17 2015-04-08  70 days
# 4       A 2016-01-30 2015-07-17 197 days
# 5       B 2015-07-28 2015-08-14 -17 days
# 6       B 2015-09-13 2015-08-27  17 days
# 7       B 2016-01-30 2015-10-13 109 days
# 8       C 2015-12-06 2015-11-25  11 days
# 9       C 2015-12-07 2016-01-05 -29 days
# 10      C 2016-01-30 2016-01-06  24 days
```

If you want to stick with `base R`, something similar:

```
start <- ave(df$start, df$user, FUN=function(x) c(x, as.Date("2016-01-30"))[-1])
df$td <- start - df$due
```

If you want to do things like add stars and take out the "days" unit, you can adjust accordingly. (i.e `sub(" .*", "", df$td)`)